# How to Exclude specific images from JavaScript Photobox animation in a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using photobox to display all images within a div in a nice gallery style. However I want to include an image in the div that I do not want in the gallery, a PDF icon, which onlick will download a pdf file. At the moment this icon appears in the gallery when clicked, I would like to know how to exclude maybe a section of the div.

Here is my code

```
 <div id="gallery">
           <td width="226" align="right"><table width="206" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="199" align="center"><a href="images/GrndFloor_dimension.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="images/GrndFloor_dimension_th.jpg" alt="Ground Floor" width="182" height="182" border="0"/></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="64" align="center" background="images/thumbs-text-holder.jpg" class="planscopy" style="background-repeat:no-repeat"><table width="151" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td width="104"><span class="planscopy" style="background-repeat:no-repeat">Ground Floor - Dimensions</span></td>
           <td width="47" align="right"><a href="docs/Ground Floor Plan - Dimensions.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="images/pdf.png" width="48" height="51"/></a></td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
      </div>

      <script type="text/javascript">
     $('#gallery').photobox('a', { thumbs: true }, imageLoaded);
    function imageLoaded() {
        console.log('image has been loaded...');
    }
```

I would like the pdf.png image not to appear in the gallery, just to be a link to the document. Is there maybe a way to exclude a div id within a div?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#gallery").photobox("a:not(:has([src$='pdf.png']))', { thumbs: true }, imageLoaded);
```

will work.(Demo for selector: http://jsfiddle.net/pUkz2/)

---

Note that the above selector is slower than if you add the class `pdf` to the `a` and use

```
$("#gallery").photobox("a:not(.pdf)', { thumbs: true }, imageLoaded);
```

I did a performance test: http://jsperf.com/pukz2

Comment: @user3810179 I made my answer more comprehensive. Please check it out and consider accepting it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see the demo and test at first, appreciate it!!

Answer (score 1):

try to give the A-Element ( PDF ) a class like "exclude" and try this JS-Code:

```
<td width="47" align="right"><a class="exclude" href="docs/Ground Floor Plan - Dimensions.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="images/pdf.png" width="48" height="51"/></a></td>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#gallery').photobox('a:not(.exclude)', { thumbs: true }, imageLoaded);
        function imageLoaded() {
        console.log('image has been loaded...');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was adding the exclude to the <img> and not the <a>. Fastest answer!!